# Стилизация PopupMenu

Tags: android, popupmenu

Есть [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html).

```
                     PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getBaseContext(), arg0);
                     popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 100, Menu.NONE, getString(R.string.item1));
                     popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 101, Menu.NONE, getString(R.string.item2));
                     popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) 
                            {

                                return true;
                            }
                      });

                     popup.show();
```

Все работает отлично. Но вот беграунд в менюшке черный и цвет текста в ней тоже черный что смотрится крайне не эстетично. 
Есть ли какая-либо возможность изменить бекграунд или цвет текста в PopupMenu?

Answer (score 2):

Все это должно настраиваться в стиле, который вы применяете для своей Активности.
Попробуйте задать фон так:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!-- Ваши настройки -->
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/фон_popup_меню</item>
</style>
```

А также можете почитать [эту](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1267) статью.

Comment: Попробывал. Как был бг черным так и остался